# Can not write the value to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a function, which needs to return true if there is a row in a table with values which user inputs.

I need to write the value to a variable which Ii return, but I got an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@ret'.

```
USE BDLab5;
GO
Create Function WasComplaint (@date date, @component varchar)
    Returns BIT
    Begin
        Declare @was int, @ret bit
        Select @was = ComponentCode from Complaints 
            Where ComplaintDate = @date AND 
            ComponentCode = (Select ComponentCode from Components Where ComponentName = @component)

        if (@was = 0)  
            @ret = 0
        else 
            @ret = 1 

        Return @ret
    End;
```

I tried different variant of if else syntax but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SET` when assigning a value to a variable.

```
USE BDLab5;
GO
Create Function WasComplaint (@date date, @component varchar)
    Returns BIT
    Begin
        Declare @was int, @ret bit
        Select @was = ComponentCode from Complaints 
            Where ComplaintDate = @date AND 
            ComponentCode = (Select ComponentCode from Components Where ComponentName = @component)

        if (@was = 0)  
            set @ret = 0
        else 
            set @ret = 1 

        Return @ret
    End;
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the word `SET` before `@ret` when you give it a value